# Group columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, object, group-concat

Hi i am new to mysql struggling with query please help.

```
SELECT 
  g_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(s_id,':',tn) 
FROM `table 
WHERE u_id = 1 
AND g_id in (1234,3211) 
ORDER by g_id
```

I am expecting:

```
{1234:{158990:30,158991:60},3211:{9988:-55,9989:65}}
```

[Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lcx8.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do it in 2 stages. First stage use a group by g_id, second stage use a group_concat without a group by.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(u_id int,g_id int,S_id int,tn int);

insert into t values
(1,1234,158990,30),
(1,1234,158991,60),
(1,3211,9988,-55),
(1,3211,9989,65);

select concat('{',group_concat(g_id,':{',gc,'}'),'}')
from
(SELECT g_id ,GROUP_CONCAT(s_id,':',tn) gc
FROM t WHERE u_id = 1 and g_id in (1234,3211) 
group by g_id
ORDER by g_id
) s
```

result

```
+------------------------------------------------------+
| concat('{',group_concat(g_id,':{',gc,'}'),'}')       |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| {1234:{158990:30,158991:60},3211:{9988:-55,9989:65}} |
+------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```